# When does $\max \lim{a, |b|} \leq a + \max \lim {|b|}$?

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\alpha_\delta >0$ be a quantity that depends *only on $\delta$* and let $I_\varepsilon$ be defined as follows:
$$I_\varepsilon = \alpha_\delta + \beta_{\varepsilon, \delta}$$
where $\beta_{\varepsilon, \delta}$ depends *both on $\varepsilon$ and on $\delta$*.

I've got stuck on the following passage which is part of a demostration I'm studying on some class notes:
$${\max\lim}_{\varepsilon \to 0}{|I_\varepsilon|} \leq {\max \lim}_{\varepsilon\to 0}\{\alpha_\delta + |\beta_{\varepsilon, \delta}|\} \leq (?) \alpha_\delta + \max\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}|\beta_{\varepsilon,\delta}|:$$
the 2nd "$\leq$" makes sense, but I can't understand the reason why $\quad{\max \lim}_{\varepsilon\to 0}\{\alpha_\delta + |\beta_{\varepsilon, \delta}|\}\quad$ is **not equal** to $\quad \alpha_\delta + \max\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}|\beta_{\varepsilon,\delta}|\quad$ if $\alpha_\delta$ doesn't depend on $\varepsilon$.

Can you help me understand it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the $\max$ taken over possible values of $\delta$, or what?

Comment: @Szmagpie it is not specified, hence the ambiguity... In my opinion $\delta$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already got this first bit:

\begin{align}\max\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}|I_\varepsilon|&=\max\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}(|\alpha_\delta+\beta_{\varepsilon,\delta}|)\\
&\le\max\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}(\alpha_\delta+|\beta_{\varepsilon,\delta}|)\\
&=\max\big(\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}(\alpha_\delta)+\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}|\beta_{\varepsilon,\delta}|\big)\\
&=\max\big(\alpha_\delta+\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}|\beta_{\varepsilon,\delta}|\big).\end{align}

Now the key point is that for any $f,g\colon\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, $$\max_x(f(x),g(x))\le \max_x(f(x))+\max_x(g(x)).$$ 
They are not necessarily equal (consider when $f=g$, for example).

In your case you have two positive "functions" of $\delta$ (namely, $\alpha_\delta$ and $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}|\beta_{\varepsilon,\delta}|$), and hence
$$\max\big(\alpha_\delta+\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}|\beta_{\varepsilon,\delta}|\big)\le\max\alpha_\delta+\max\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}|\beta_{\varepsilon,\delta}|.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains everything! :)